# How to calculate difference between two dates in workdays

Tags: sql-server

I need to calculate difference in workdays between two dates. Is there a built in function for this in SQL Server? Can someone please provide an example on how to do this?

Comment: Can you give an example of the two dates and your expected result?

Comment: Want to take into account public holidays? If so you'll need a table to store them as they change by country/region.

Comment: You realise you've marked as the right answer one which gives a totally incorrect result? Just plug in `3/16/2013` and `3/23/2013` as start and end date (thats saturday to saturday). How many working days do you expect there - `5` i'd hope. The answer you've marked gives `7`

Comment: You are right. Still i got information i needed ty both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something I wrote quickly. Just encapsulate it into a function or whatever you need.

```
declare @StartDate datetime
declare @EndDate datetime

declare @TotalDiff int
declare @NumberOfWeekends int

SET @StartDate = '3/12/2013'
SET @EndDate = '3/22/2013'
SET @NumberOfWeekends = 0
SET @TotalDiff = DATEDIFF(d,@StartDate, @EndDate)

If @TotalDiff > 7 
    SET @NumberOfWeekends = @TotalDiff / 7
else if DATEPART(dd, @EndDate) < DATEPART(DD, @StartDate)
    SET @NumberOfWeekends = 1

select (@TotalDiff - 2*@NumberOfWeekends) as TotalWorkDays
```

Comment: This is far too simplistic - just change your start and end date to successive saturdays and you get a result of 7 instead of the expected 5

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing built in to SQL Server to directly give you number of working days between two dates, however there are a few built-in functions which will enable you to write one.

Firstly, a few caveats

- The world cannot agree what a "Working Day" is. For most of us it's Saturday and Sunday. For most of the Middle East it's Friday & Saturday (with Sunday being a normal working day)
- The world most certainly cannot agree on what constitutes a public holiday, which are almost always considered non-working days.

You have not specified how you would like to handle these cases so lets make some assumptions:

- Saturday and Sunday will be non-working days
- Public holidays will not be taken into acount

Now, determining if a particular days is saturday or sunday in sql is easy, given a `@date` of type `DateTime`:

```
IF DATENAME(dw,@date) IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
```

With that in mind, given a start and end date, you can just count incrementally from `@startDate` to `@endDate`

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '2013-01-01'
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '2013-01-20'

DECLARE @currDate DATETIME = @startDate
DECLARE @numDays INT = 0
WHILE @currDate<@endDate
BEGIN
   IF DATENAME(dw,@currDate) NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
     SET @numDays = @numDays + 1

   SET @currDate = DATEADD(day,1,@currDate)
END
SELECT @numDays
```

Note: This is non-inclsive so wont count `@endDate`. You could change it to be inclusive by changing `WHILE @currDate<@endDate` to `WHILE @currDate<=@endDate`

Answer (score 0):

My solution does not count the @EndDate, so if you need to change that, just add 1 to @d2.

First, I calculate the number of days from an "initial" day (which happens to be 1/1/1900, a Monday) to @StartDate and @EndDate:

```
DECLARE @d1 int = DATEDIFF(Day, 0, @StartDate);
DECLARE @d2 int = DATEDIFF(Day, 0, @EndDate);
```

Then, the total number of days between @StartDate and @EndDate is:

```
@d2 - @d1
```

From this, I substract the number of Sundays and the number of Saturdays in the interval, each calculated as a difference simlar to the total days, but now for whole weeks (7 days). To get the number of whole weeks, I use integer division by 7 and the fact that the "initial" day (0) is a Monday. The number of Sundays in the interval is

```
@d2/7 - @d1/7
```

and the number of Saturdays is

```
(@d2+1)/7 - (@d1+1)/7
```

Putting all together, my solution is:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '20180101'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '20180201'

DECLARE @d1 int = DATEDIFF(Day, 0, @StartDate)
DECLARE @d2 int = DATEDIFF(Day, 0, @EndDate)

SELECT @d2 - @d1 - (@d2/7 - @d1/7) - ((@d2+1)/7 - (@d1+1)/7) AS workdays
```