# Using Calendar table to calculate fiscal week of year and business days in week

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a calendar table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FIN_CalendarTable](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [fiscalStart] [datetime] NULL,
    [fiscalEnd] [datetime] NULL,
    [isHoliday] [int] NOT NULL,
    [isWorkday] [int] NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FIN_CalendarTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I am wanting to calculate the qyt of business days in each week of the fiscal year.  I have the following query which returns the fiscal weeks and each business day of the fiscal period (250 records):

```
    SELECT  dbo.CalendarTable.fiscalStart
      , dbo.CalendarTable.fiscalEnd
      , COUNT(*)
      , dbo.CalendarTable.monthOfYearName
      , dbo.CalendarTable.monthStart
      , dbo.CalendarTable.monthEnd
      , DATEDIFF(DAY, dbo.CalendarTable.fiscalStart, [date]) / 7 + 1 WeekOfFiscalYear
FROM    dbo.CalendarTable
WHERE   dbo.CalendarTable.isHoliday=0
          AND dbo.CalendarTable.isWorkday=1
        AND ( dbo.CalendarTable.date  >= CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/07/2012',103)
              AND dbo.CalendarTable.date <= CONVERT(DATETIME,'30/06/2013',103) ) 
GROUP BY dbo.CalendarTable.fiscalStart
      , dbo.CalendarTable.fiscalEnd
      , dbo.CalendarTable.monthOfYearName
      , dbo.CalendarTable.monthStart
      , dbo.CalendarTable.monthEnd
      , [dbo].[CalendarTable].[date]
```

I realise that this is occuring becuase the group by inlcudes the [dbo].[CalendarTable].[date] column.  Is there are better way to structure this query so that 52 (or when appropriate 53) records are returned with a total of the business days in each fiscal week?

I could probably achieve the aggregate within the application but wanted to achieve a nicer set of results if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I’d rather try to create an UDF that would give me the number of work days or total number of weeks than trying to get this info from query itself.  You have all these columns in GROUP BY statement only so you can count the number of records and you can probably simplify the query by using UDF.

Here is a post that shows how to calculate the difference between two dates in workdays. 
[How to calculate difference between two dates in workdays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431498/how-to-calculate-difference-between-two-dates-in-workdays)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there are better way to structure this query so that 52 (or when
>   appropriate 53) records are returned with a total of the business days
>   in each fiscal week?

It's not entirely clear what you mean by *business days*, but if by that you mean work days, then I think you need something along these lines.

```
SELECT fiscalStart
     , fiscalEnd
     , sum(isWorkday)
FROM dbo.CalendarTable
WHERE date >= CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/07/2012',103)
  AND date <= CONVERT(DATETIME,'30/06/2013',103)
GROUP BY fiscalStart
       , fiscalEnd
ORDER BY fiscalStart
```

This assumes that, for each date, "fiscalStart" means the first day of the fiscal week and "fiscalEnd" means the last day of the fiscal week.  If that's not what those columns mean, edit your question, paste a couple of weeks worth of INSERT statements, along with expected output.