# Pl/SQL and building out monthly data from Start and Stop Dates

Tags: oracle, plsql

PL/SQL is not my strong suite.  I am decent with SQL, but I have a challenge that I could really use your help with, if possible. I am using SQL Developer, if that helps.

I have a table that is a join from two other tables, but suffice it to say, it has the following applicaple columns:

```
FTE_NAME              (VARCHAR2)
PRIMARY_BILLALBE_ROLE (VARCHAR2)
INVOICABLE_ALLOCATION (NUMBER)
CONTRACTED_FTE        (NUMBER)
FTE_COUNTRY           (VARCHAR2)
BILLING_START_DATE    (DATE)
BILLING_END_DATE      (DATE)
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:
 I have actually done this using VBA and excel and it works great, but now the data is on an Oracle Server and its time for an update.

Example Rows:

```
|   FTE_NAME | PRIMARY_BILLABLE_ROLE | INVOICEABLE_ALLOCATION | CONTRACTED_FTE | FTE_COUNTRY | BILLING_START_DATE | BILLING_END_DATE |
|------------|-----------------------|------------------------|----------------|-------------|--------------------|------------------|
| John Smith |     Associate Manager |                      1 |              1 |         USA |   January, 01 2013 |     May, 01 2013 |
| John Smith |               Manager |                      1 |              1 |         USA |       May, 02 2013 |           (null) |
```

What I would need to happen is that the PL/SQL code would build a monthly table and row by row include or exclude the row in that month, so from `01-JAN-2013` to `05-MAY-2013`, the monthly table might look like this now with a MONTH COLUMN up front:

```
|           MONTHLY |   FTE_NAME | PRIMARY_BILLABLE_ROLE | INVOICEABLE_ALLOCATION | CONTRACTED_FTE | FTE_COUNTRY | BILLING_START_DATE | BILLING_END_DATE |
|-------------------|------------|-----------------------|------------------------|----------------|-------------|--------------------|------------------|
|  January, 01 2013 | John Smith |     Associate Manager |                      1 |              1 |         USA |   January, 01 2013 |    May, 01 2013  |
| February, 01 2013 | John Smith |     Associate Manager |                      1 |              1 |         USA |   January, 01 2013 |    May, 01 2013  |
|    March, 01 2013 | John Smith |     Associate Manager |                      1 |              1 |         USA |   January, 01 2013 |    May, 01 2013  |
|    April, 01 2013 | John Smith |     Associate Manager |                      1 |              1 |         USA |   January, 01 2013 |    May, 01 2013  |
|      May, 01 2013 | John Smith |     Associate Manager |                      1 |              1 |         USA |   January, 01 2013 |    May, 01 2013  |
|      May, 01 2013 | John Smith |               Manager |                      1 |              1 |         USA |       May, 02 2013 |           (null) |
```

The lines for `MAY` would both be included in the `01-MAY-2013` rows, because that manager still worked as an Associate Manager for those few days.  I used the start and end dates to calculate how many days.

The big part I need help with is how to get the table to build with a `MONTHLY` column using the first day of the month.  There will 1000s of lines and each building everyday.  I would have this code running in a view which will feed report and dashboards.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

David

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Comment: You might want to consider creating a BUSINESS_CALENDAR table which contains valid business days, an indicator of which fiscal week, month, and year a particular calendar day is in (fiscal calendars typically follow a 4-4-5 schedule - [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4%E2%80%934%E2%80%935_calendar)), and any other calendar-related data which is appropriate for the business you're looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can populate desired dates from scratch like in this example query:

```
with report_params as (
  -- just to introduce variables 
  select 
    2013 year_value,
    4    start_month,
    6    end_month
  from  dual
),
report_months as (
  -- list of first dates of all required months 
  select 
    add_months( -- add months to
        trunc( -- January, 1st of year from parameters
          to_date(
            (select year_value from report_params), 
            'yyyy'
          ),
          'yyyy'
        ), 
        (select start_month from report_params) + level - 2
    )
  from 
    dual 
  connect by 
    -- select number of rows (levels) from start_month to end_month
    level <= (select end_month - start_month + 1 from report_params)
)
select * from report_months;
```

Another possibility is to analyze a table and generate diapason between minimum and maximum values:

```
with bound_months as (
  select 
    min(trunc(billing_start_date,'mm')) as first_month,
    max(trunc(billing_start_date,'mm')) as last_month
  from 
    applicable_columns
),
report_months as (
  select 
    add_months(
      (select first_month from bound_months),
      level - 1
    )
      as first_date
  from 
    dual 
  connect by 
    -- select number of rows (levels) from start_month to end_month
    level <= (select months_between(last_month,first_month)+1 from bound_months)

)
select * from report_months;
```

After that you can join list of months to data table/view with applicable columns:

```
with bound_months as (
  select 
    min(trunc(billing_start_date,'mm')) as first_month,
    max(trunc(billing_start_date,'mm')) as last_month
  from 
    applicable_columns
),
report_months as (
  select 
    add_months(
      (select first_month from bound_months),
      level - 1
    )
      as first_date
  from 
    dual 
  connect by 
    -- select number of rows (levels) from start_month to end_month
    level <= (select months_between(last_month,first_month)+1 from bound_months)

)
select
  months.first_date, 
  data.*
from 
 report_months      months,
 applicable_columns data
where 
 data.billing_start_date < add_months(months.first_date,1) 
 and
 nvl(data.billing_end_date, months.first_date) >= months.first_date
order by
  first_date, fte_name, primary_billable_role
```

**[<kbd>SQLFiddle test</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d71d/8)**

Comment: Thank You so much for this...I will give it a go and reply with any questions.

Comment: This is really amazing and it is working perfectly!  Thank You..if you are willing..here is my next step with this and I am not sure if it should be within the same view or another view.  I need to calculate for each "first_date", the number of days each person worked.  So for example...John Smith would have worked, 23 days in January 2013, 20 days in February 2013, etc.. and 1 days in May 2013.  Any hints on how I can accomplish this?  Thanks again..David

Comment: Work days would just be Monday - Friday, I am not worried about holidays....I found this to calc. workdays...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431498/how-to-calculate-difference-between-two-dates-in-workdays

Comment: @Ewaver Seems that there are another question which must be asked separately ... Anyway, please check [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d71d/14).